# How to substitute variable in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plsql

Hi I am working in Postgres. I have below code

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    item integer;
begin
    item:=5;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_data;
    CREATE temp TABLE temp_data AS
select current_timestamp + interval '1 day' as op;
 
END $$;
select * from temp_data;
```

In the above code in the Text '1 Day' I would like to replace 1 with variable item. Can someone please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can concat value with item variable

```
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + (item::text || ' day')::interval AS op
```

Answer (score 2):

Intervals [overload](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) the multiplication operator with `DOUBLE PRECISION` (that `INT` can be autocast to):

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    item integer;
begin
    item:=5;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp_data;
    CREATE temp TABLE temp_data AS
    select current_timestamp + item * interval '1 day' as op;

END
$$;
```